# Why do I get a segmentation fault while calculating the one's complement of a binary number?

Tags: c++

I have written a C++ code to store a binary number using a doubly linked list where the LSB is stored in the head node.

Whenever I enter '0' in the head node I get a segmentation fault while calculating the one's complement, however I do not have this problem when I enter '1' in the head node.

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
 int bin;
 node *prev,*next;
 public:
  node(int b)
  {
   bin=b;
   prev=NULL;
   next=NULL;
  }
 friend class II;
};

class II
{
 node *head,*tail;
 int digits;
 public:
  II()
  {
   head=NULL;
   tail=NULL;
  }

 void dig()
 {  
  cout<<"Enter the number of digits: ";
  cin>>digits;
  if(digits<2)
  {
   cout<<"Please enter more digits: ";
   cin>>digits;
  }
  else{}
 }

 void create()
 {
  int y;
  if(head==NULL)
  {
   node *q;
   cout<<"Enter binary digit: ";
   cin>>y;
   if(y<0||y>1)
   {
    cout<<"Enter again: ";
    cin>>y;
   }
   q=new node(y);
   head=q;
   head->next=NULL;
   head->prev=NULL;
  }
  else
  {
   cout<<"ll created";
  }
 }

 void insert()
 {
  node* temp=head;
  node* q;
  int i,y;
  i=1;
  while(i<digits)
  {
   cout<<"Enter the next digit";
   cin>>y;
   if(y<0||y>1)
   {
    cout<<"Please enter again: ";
    cin>>y;
   }
   else
   {
    q=new node(y);
    temp->next=q;
    q->next=NULL;
    q->prev=temp;
    tail=q;
    temp=temp->next;
    i++;
   }
  }
 }

 void disp()
 {
  node *temp=tail;
  while(temp!=NULL)
  {
   cout<<temp->bin;
   temp=temp->prev;
  }
  cout<<endl;
 } 

 void neg()
 {
  node *temp=tail;
  while(temp!=NULL)
  {
   if(temp->bin==0)
   {  
    cout<<"1";
    temp=temp->prev;
   }  
   if(temp->bin==1)
   {  
    cout<<"0";
    temp=temp->prev;                                                                                           
   }
  }
  cout<<endl;
 }  
};

int main()
{
 II a;
 a.dig();
 a.create();
 a.insert();
 a.disp();
 a.neg();
 return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of digits: 4
Enter binary digit: 1
Enter the next digit1
Enter the next digit0
Enter the next digit0
0011
1100
```

And:

```
Enter the number of digits: 4
Enter binary digit: 0
Enter the next digit0
Enter the next digit1
Enter the next digit1
1100
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 0):

As Nathan noted, a debugger is a key tool for a programmer.  Stepping through a program line by line and looking for the problem is a key skill for success.

I used a couple of tools to reproduce your problem.  'gdb' is the debugger on Linux.  'valgrind' is a Linux tool that will look for a variety of error including bad memory access.

Valgrind pointed to the neg function.

```
void neg()
 {
  node *temp=tail;
  while(temp!=NULL)
  {
   if(temp->bin==0)
   {  
    cout<<"1";
    temp=temp->prev;  // likely temp is first node so temp->prev == nullptr
   }  
   // missing an 'else' statement here?
   if(temp->bin==1)  // crash here accessing a nullptr
   {  
    cout<<"0";
    temp=temp->prev;                                                                                           
   }
  }
  cout<<endl;
 }  
};
```

I added an 'else' statement and the program worked as excepted for your test cases.

There may be other errors, test your code well. Investigate 'unit testing' for more about testing.